# How to use the Tkinter canvas.find_below?

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tkinter

I'm using Python 2.7 with Tkinter on the PyCharm IDE (Community Edition 3.4) on a Mac OSX Mountain Lion. I'm trying to build a simple checkers game using Tkinter. So far I have created a board as well as been able to create the game pieces. I've managed to get to the point where two players can drag the pieces on the board. But here's where things get hairy--I'm not able to find out how to restrict the pieces only to the "black" squares on the board. I can't upload images on Stack Overflow yet, because I'm a noobie without reputation. So here's a link to the checkers board I created: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZTzx.jpg

Within the class that I have created, I use a "canvas.tag_bind" to the pieces when they are pressed in hopes that the code will tell me whether the grey or orange game piece, when clicked, will show me whether the piece is on a "red" square or a "black" square.

In my code for the class, I have the following "canvas.tag_bind" statement:

```
canvas.tag_bind("oval", "<ButtonPress-1>", OnOverlappingRed)
```

Once my mouse is pressed over a grey or orange piece, the following function is executed to ascertain whether the piece is on a black square or red square:

```
def OnOverlappingRed(event):
        item_below = canvas.find_below("oval")
        print item_below
        print canvas.gettags(item_below[0])[0]
```

But when I execute my program this is the output I get when I press a grey or orange piece on the board:

```
(64,)
red
```

Shouldn't Tkinter give me the index of the square below the piece I press? I went through Tkinter documentation and that was the exact definition of "find_below" -- it returns the item that is below the item in question.

So what is going on here and how can I fix this problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `find_below` is doing what you think it's doing. It doesn't find the item *under* the oval, it finds the item lower in the stacking order, which could be any item on the canvas. Unless you change the stacking order, it will always return the same item for the same reference item.

Instead of `find_below`, you probably want to use `find_closest`, `find_overlapping` or `find_enclosing`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. How does one go about changing the stacking order in Tkinter?

Comment: @user2551765: with `lift` and `lower` methods

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys. I tried using canvas.find_overlapping in the following way to find the square that is underneath the circular piece like so:

```
def OverlappingSquare(event):
        print canvas.find_overlapping(40, 80, 90, 130)
```

40,80,90,130 are the coordinates of a black square which has a grey piece on top of it. This is the output I get when I use the above "find_overlapping" command:

```
(1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 65)
```

I have no idea what this tuple means. Can someone explain the meaning of this?

EDIT:
I found out the answer to this problem --
The tuple shows all the squares surrounding the particular square who's dimensions are given to the find_overlapping() method. This is the following code I used to give me the exact reference number of the particular square underneath the circular piece which is clicked:

```
def OverlappingSquare(event):
        item_below = canvas.find_overlapping(event.x,event.y,event.x,event.y)[0]
        print item_below
```

This prints out the exact square reference number (which can be 1, 3, 5, 7, etc.)